# Android: get response from the servlet

Tags: android, servlets, authentication

I have a login servlet that looks like this:

```
@WebServlet(name="AndroidResponse", urlPatterns={"/androidres.do"})
public class AndroidResponse extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
    throws ServletException, IOException {
        PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
        String un,pw;
        un=request.getParameter("username");
        pw=request.getParameter("password");
        if(un.equalsIgnoreCase("test") && pw.equals("test"))
            out.print(1);
        else
            out.print(0);
    }
}
```

I'm trying to access it in the main activity like this:

```
response = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost("http://androidres.do/AndroidResponse", postParameters);
                        String res=response.toString();
```

I get an error saying that the host does not exist. What is the correct way to get the respnse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/androidres.do` is not the host part of the servlet URL, but the path that comes after the host. The correct URL for calling your servlet should be `http://YOUR_SERVLET_HOST/androidres.do`.

So you need to know how to call the webserver that runs the servlet from the android device, for example:

```
response = CustomHttpClient.executeHttpPost("http://192.168.0.100:8080/androidres.do", postParameters);
String res=response.toString();
```

if the webserver can be reached on IP address 192.168.0.100 and port 8080.